# remove readonly attribute using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.show_edit').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.edit_faq').show();
        $(this).parent().prev().find('.remove_att').removeAttr( "readonly" ); // this working perfect
        $(this).next().find('.remove_text').removeAttr( "readonly" ); // this is not working
    });
   
</script>
```

```css
<?php foreach ($faq as $faq): ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" id="question" class="form-control remove_att" value="<?php echo $faq['faq_question'] ?>" placeholder="Enter the question" readonly="readonly" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" class="edit_all">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm show_edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="<?php echo $faq['faq_id'] ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit_faq" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Save" style="display: none"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" ></i></button>
            <button  type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete_faq"  id="<?php echo $faq['faq_id'] ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer : </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea class="form-control remove_text" id="answer" rows="5" placeholder="Type your answer..." required="required" readonly ><?php echo $faq['faq_answer'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

i'm doing inline edit using save and edit button with the help of jquery.
when i click on edit button input type="text" and textarea remove the readonly attribute. where input type="text" is working correctly,now i want to remove the readonly from textarea how to do this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: $("#id").removeAttr('readonly'); are you familiar with this

Comment: check your code of line $(this).next().fin d('.remove_text').removeAttr( "readonly" ); that have space in `find`

Comment: i did, it is not working, you check my javascript code

Comment: i corrected that, still issue exists

Comment: @Rakesh can you add the rendered `HTML` instead of  `PHP` code? It will be much helpful

Comment: how to add the rendered html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find parent of .show_edit then again find its parent.

Your textarea is present in next div where we find .remove_text class for remove readonly

so try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $('.show_edit').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.edit_faq').show();
        $(this).parent().prev().find('.remove_att').removeAttr( "readonly" ); 
        $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.remove_text').removeAttr( "readonly" ); 
     })
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: If my answer is right then you can select as right ... if you are unable to vote.

Answer (score 4):

Your **.show_edit** button wrapped in 2 divs:

`div.edit_all`  and  `div.form-group`

And, your textarea is located in the next *div.form-group*,
So, try this:

```
$('.show_edit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.edit_faq').show();
    $(this).parent().prev().find('.remove_att').removeAttr( "readonly" );
    $(this).closest('.form-group').next().find('.remove_text').removeAttr( "readonly" );
         // ^find the closest div.form-group parent 
});
```

Comment: thanks it works, i cant upvote, i;m soo sorry , I don't have that much reputation